# The physics behind the Starshade

Tags: orbital-mechanics, imaging, exoplanet

The Starshade is a space telescope with a large occulter that can fly off and block the light of a star so its telescope can picture the surrounding exoplanets:

I sort of understand the optics behind its shape; the light that bleeds around the edges their waves cancel each other out. But I can't get the math of the distance right. Say it wants to image the Trappist system, which is 4e17m away and its star is 7e7m in diameter and the shade is 10m. So the distance/size ratio would be 5e9, thus the shade would have to be 5e10m (50,000,000km) from the telescope right? Or is my math wrong?

Isn't that way too far?! Why is it so big? The orbital-mechanics behind it are also problematic. Will they orbit the Earth? Getting in an orbit 5e9m from the Earth is rather energetically expensive, not to mention the difference in orbital period they'd have to deal with.

I guess these are a lot of questions, but I can't find a proper explanation of the New Worlds mission (it's real name). So I'm hoping someone can explain the gist of it to me.

Comment: I'm not sure this is all correct, so I'll post it as a comment instead of an answer, but the angular `diameter = 2*arctan(d/2D)` where d is the diameter of the object observed and D is the distance to the telescope. If we take Deneb at 0.002" (arcsecs)  how far does a 10m shade needs to be to have the same angular diameter? `0.002" = 2*arctan(10/2x) => x = 2/(5*tan(0.002")) = 12,000m = 12km`?? Does that sound right to anyone?

Comment: Hmm, so according to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter#Use_in_astronomy , the `angular diameter = (206,265) d / D arcseconds.` => 1 million km?

Comment: Just to point out that Deneb is a super giant of a star where Trappist is ultra cool dwarf so 50 mil km does not sound out of the possibilities.

Comment: Yes [Trappist-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRAPPIST-1#/media/File:Comparison_of_the_sizes_of_the_TRAPPIST-1_planets_with_Solar_System_bodies.jpg) is small, but it is by far the most interesting star system we've found to date. 40 ly out, 3 habitable-zone planets, we'd want to image those, find out if they are actually habitable and if they are, send a satellite. So I'd like to stick to that example.

Comment: You should add links to your numbers. Where are you getting your quoted distance and diameter for the star? You shouldn't expect answers to be based on unsourced or poorly sourced values.

Comment: Also the idea that the shade should be a similar angular size as the star is wrong. The size should be that which minimizes the amount of scattered light from the star, (which is much larger) but not so big that it hides the planets of interest. Still it does seem like quite a challenge!

Comment: @uhoh I think the angular diameter of the star is close enough approximation.

Comment: This question might be better answered in the astronomy SE...

Comment: @ventsyv Here in SXSE and many other technical SE sites it is always good practice to include links to non-obvious numerical data. It's just good practice, even if someone leaves a comment saying they think it's right.

Comment: @uhoh I would've if it was an answer. Asking for references in a comment is a bit too much in my opinion.

Comment: @ventsyv I think it's better to have a certain level of consistency here,. Numbers are not pulled out of the air. Numbers come from somewhere, one shouldn't hide the source they are using, forcing every reader to independently go and check them in case they are wrong. This is bad practice and bad form and you should not encourage it. It's helpful to future readers as well. It may be different in worldbuilding.

Comment: @ventsyv: It's about satellite sensors. It's on-topic. It is never correct to close on-topic questions just because they are *also* (probably) on-topic somewhere else.

Comment: A more serious problem with this question is the choice of exoplanet system. The star is only about the size of Jupiter, and the exoplanets b, c, d, e, f, g are all less than 1% the distance from the star than Jupiter is from our sun for example. So really the question somewhat loaded by choosing a particularly tiny start with extremely close, tight planetary orbits as if it were a typical example of an object to be observed.

Comment: @uhoh aren't you a negative Nancy. I don't see why you would doubt such uncontroversial, basic factual data as the size and distance of a star. Plus the source is rather obvious: Wikipedia. And it may be true that Trappist 1 is a particularly difficult system, but it's really close as well, so maybe that alleviates the challenges from its smallness. They found it after all.

Comment: @Herman good practice is good practice. Links, verifiable sources, these help keep information in SE more reliable and up-to-date than the more wild corners of the internet. Since *your question is based on a set of numbers seeming to be incompatible*, adding your source helps to show you've done your homework. Suggestions are meant to be helpful, and usually people catch on quickly to this and do a good job of self-policing. Systems like Trappist are found with transit photometry and doppler spectroscopy because they don't have any of the same limitations that direct imaging does.

Comment: @Herman As I mentioned above, the shade just needs to be small enough so that the telescope can see the planet, it could still be much wider than the angular extent of the central star. The physics of how the shade minimizes light leaked around the edges is probably not so simple. I'll see what I can find out. Also, I'll add a bounty to the question which may attract some answers form people who understand this diffraction problem better than I do.

Comment: @Herman et al. See Figure 2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.6063 and Figure 1 (actually the entire paper) in https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1105

Comment: @uhoh Thanks! That is a very relevant paper. They assume a much larger 50-m starshade, at a distance of 70,000-100,000 km from the telescope located at the Earth-Sun L2 point. So that answers my question whether it will orbit the earth. And it seems indeed that imaging the Trappist system is not in scope of this mission. In fact they only hope to image 1 to 3 Earth-like planets in the entirety of its mission. That is a rather disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

Your math is wrong, the starshade operates at 50 000 km from the telescope. See the [Exo-S starshade report](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj85v-TuovWAhXMJFAKHT9XCSwQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fexoplanets.nasa.gov%2Fstdt%2FExo-S_Starshade_Probe_Class_Final_Report_150312_URS250118.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFkjI4rpWM2H0ZQ12g5zghK-8qcCQ), executive summary, page 4.

The physics behind the starshade are the following:

If there were no diffraction, putting the starshade in front of the star would compeletely block the light of the star, because when seen from the telescope it has a larger angular diameter than the star.
However, due to diffraction, the light from the star is not completely blocked: it forms an [Arago spot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arago_spot). This means the telescope still sees some light from the star, and that can hide the signal from the planets orbiting the star.

The shape of the starshade is designed to minimize the intensity of this Arago spot. The petals are a way to do that, and still use a completely opaque material (i.e. not using partially transparent materials). [Here](https://www.princeton.edu/~hcil/papers/Cady07a.pdf)'s an article deriving their shape.

Comment: Thanks for that report! That it operates on a different distance doesn't mean that my math is wrong though. It might be because they pick other target stars. And then I still wonder, how is my math wrong?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you showed "the right math" in your answer. Right now your statement isn't so helpful; there are no numbers here, nor equations, and not so much in the way of explanations either. It would be better if you relied less on the links, and added a little more explanation here. Links tend to rot, and so the value of an answer can decay over time if it depends on the links to do the explaining.

Comment: @Herman: the angular diameter of the starshade as seen from the telescope gives the inner working angle of the system, not to the angular diameter of the star. The IWA corresponds to the orbital radius of the closest planet the system can see, divided by the distance from the telescope to the star. See the drawing in page 4-2 of the report (page 65 of the pdf).